# Named Pipe communication between two network services

Tags: c#, security, service, named-pipes

I have a (.NET 4.0) Windows service (running under the "NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" credential) running on different machines, and these services are trying to communicate with each other via Named Pipes.
Both machines are part of WORKGROUP, not on a domain.

This is how the named pipe Client is created:

```
   ClientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(%ServerName%, PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
```

This is how the named pipe Server is created:

```
ServerStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 254, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
```

When the client attempts to connect to the server (by calling ClientStream.Connect()), the following exception is thrown (on the Client side):

> System.IO.IOException: **Logon failure: unknown user name or bad
>   password.**

The following Security Audit failures were found in the Security event log (on the Server side):

> Logon Failure: Reason: **Unknown user name or bad password**  User
>   Name: %ClientName%$ Domain: Workgroup Logon Type: 3 Logon Process:
>   NtLmSsp Authentication Package: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
>   Workstation Name: %ClientName%
>
> Logon attempt by: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0 Logon account:
>   %ClientName%$ Source Workstation: %ClientName% Error Code: 0xC0000064

I have tried the following (without success):

- Granting PipeAccessRights.FullControl to "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
  SERVICE", on the ServerStream
- Granting PipeAccessRights.FullControl to "Everyone", on the ServerStream
- Creating the ClientStream with TokenImpersonationLevel = Impersonation (so the server could impersonate the client’s security
  context [NetworkService] on its local system)

It appears that the client presents its machine account (**%ClientName%$**) credentials to connect to the server, but these credentials are rejected by the server (as evidenced by the Security Audit failure above).

Is there a way that the named pipe connection can be established between these two Network Services?

Comment: "Network Service running on different machines" - Do you mean you have a windows service running under the "NT Authority\Network Service" credential?

Comment: Also, you may get better assistance with Named Pipe permission between servers over at serverfault.com

Comment: Correct (Network Service credentials) - I've updated my post